# How to get react jsx "to: "/profile"" to redirect and load the profile page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

throughout my app I am using reach router to handle navigation between my pages.

However, I found a navbar component that I enjoy and brought it into my app. I am not sure why, but the "to: "/profile"" button does not actually navigate and load my http://localhost:3000/profile page.

It does change the html address to show http://localhost:3000/profile, but it does not redirect and load the profile page. I have to refresh the browser for it to do so.

Any ideas on how to get this "My Profile" button to actually redirect and load the profile page? Could I use reach router "navigate(/"profile")" in this syntax? It doesn't seem to fit when I try. Thanks!

**Navbar.js**

```
import { BorderStyle } from "@material-ui/icons";
import React from "react";
import * as ReactNavbar from "react-responsive-animate-navbar";
import Logo from "../Assets/Media/ToolioLogoSmall.png"
import { navigate, Link } from "@reach/router"; //not using this currently, but it is used for navigation throughout the rest of my app.
 

export default function Navbar() {
  console.log(ReactNavbar.ReactNavbar)
  return (
    <div style={style.background}>
      <ReactNavbar.ReactNavbar style={style.background}
        color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
        logo={Logo}
        menu={[
          { name: "HOME", to: "/Explore" },
          { name: "ARTICLES", to: "/articles" },
          { name: "My Profile", to: "/profile" },
          { name: "CONTACT", to: "/contact" },
        ]}
        social={[
          {
            name: "Linkedin",
            url: "https://www.linkedin.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "linkedin-in"],
          },
          {
            name: "Facebook",
            url: "https://www.facebook.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "facebook-f"],
          },
          {
            name: "Instagram",
            url: "https://www.instagram.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "instagram"],
          },
          {
            name: "Twitter",
            url: "http://www.twitter.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "twitter"],
          },
        ]}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I saw the package you have used:

```
import * as ReactNavbar from "react-responsive-animate-navbar
```

found that you are using the provided sample code of this package.
the "menu" here is used for the presentational purpose, I don't think the package has used it as a router link or navlink.
Wrap each of the menu objects as NavLink something like this:

```
menu={[
          { name: "HOME", to: "/Explore" },
          { name: "ARTICLES", to: "/articles" },
          { name: "My Profile", to: "/profile" },
          { name: "CONTACT", to: "/contact" },
        ]}
```

try this instead:

```
menu={[
          { name: "HOME", to: {<Link to="/explore"/>} },
          { name: "ARTICLES", to: {<Link to="/articles"/>} }
    ]}
```

or you can use navlaink too.

Comment: Hi @Tina, I appreciate your response! I added my response below as an answer since it included code and a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

@Tina

I appreciate you taking the time to respond!! I implemented the snipped you suggested but it looks like the syntax is off for some reason. I also installed and imported react-router-dom and used .

Here is the current code shown in the image below. Any ideas on getting your suggestion to work? I assume the end solution here will be some sort of workaround.

```
import { BorderStyle } from "@material-ui/icons";
import React from "react";
import * as ReactNavbar from "react-responsive-animate-navbar";
import Logo from "../Assets/Media/ToolioLogoSmall.png"
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { navigate } from "@reach/router";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
 

export default function Navbar({ setSignedIn }) {
  console.log(ReactNavbar.ReactNavbar)
  return (
    <Router>
    <div style={style.background}>
      <ReactNavbar.ReactNavbar style={style.background}
        color="rgb(25, 25, 25)"
        logo={Logo}
        menu={[
          { name: "Home", to: {<Link to="/explore"/>} },
          { name: "My Profile", to: {<Link to="/articles">} },
          { name: "About Us", to: {<Link to="/AboutUs"/>} },
        ]}
        social={[
          {
            name: "Linkedin",
            url: "https://www.linkedin.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "linkedin-in"],
          },
          {
            name: "Facebook",
            url: "https://www.facebook.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "facebook-f"],
          },
          {
            name: "Instagram",
            url: "https://www.instagram.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "instagram"],
          },
          {
            name: "Twitter",
            url: "http://www.twitter.com/",
            icon: ["fab", "twitter"],
          },
        ]}
      />
            <button
          style={style.signouticon}
          onClick={() => {
            (async function () {
              try {
                await Auth.signOut({ global: true });
                setSignedIn(undefined);
                navigate("/");
              } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
              }
            })();
          }}
        >
          sign out
        </button>
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }

  const style = {
    background: {
      backgroundColor: "black",
      borderStyle: "10px black"
    },
  };
```

[image]